Animate circular ProgressView()
In my Swift application for macOS, I tried to add a ProgressView(), first linear, then circular.
I can easily animate the linear one, but not the circular one.

Here is my code:
var progressAction1 = 0.0

// linear
ProgressView(value: progressAction1ProgressView(value: progressAction1)
    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: progressAction1)
    // .padding(.horizontal, 20)

// circular
ProgressView(value: progressAction1)
    .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: progressAction1)
    .progressViewStyle(.circular)
    // .padding(.horizontal, 20) 


This is SwiftUI code. You should add that tag to your question.

(Sadly I don't know a lot about SwiftUI animation. I can make Core Animation sit up and dance, but I'm still learning SwiftUI,)

It seems like circular progress views on macOS just simply doesn't support animations out of the box. Let's hope it does in a future macOS version.
You can kind of make this work by creating an Animatable wrapper around ProgressView.
struct AnimatableCircularProgressView<Value: BinaryFloatingPoint & VectorArithmetic>: View, Animatable {
    var progress: Value
    
    var animatableData: Value {
        get { progress }
        set { progress = newValue }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ProgressView(value: progress)
            .progressViewStyle(.circular)
    }
}

Usage:
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var progressAction1 = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        AnimatableCircularProgressView(progress: progressAction1)
            .animation(.easeIn(duration: 1), value: progressAction1)
        Button("Foo") {
            progressAction1 += 0.5
        }
    }
}


Thanks ! But I notice that the animation is a little jerky towards the end?

@iStuces Well, this is not a natively supported animation, so that much is to be expected. The way this works is SwiftUI sets animatableData to different values every frame.
